# Mailgun: Check if a user has already subscribed

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm using Mailgun API for sending emails in my app. I get to notice that if a user subscribes, and try to subscribe again, mailgun returns an error `The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!` showing my root directory and the line number. What I want to do is to first of all check if a user has been subscribed, before going ahead to try subscribing. How can I achieve this, please?
I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [mailgun api documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists) you can do a request like this: GET /lists//members/